# How to search from spring cache using where condition?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching

In the spring boot application let the entity is as follows

```
public class Employee{
   private String location;
   private String name;
   private String lastName;
}
```

In my service, I am using @Cachable to find all

```
@Cacheable(value="employees")
public List<Employee> findAll() {
  return employeeDAO.findAll();
}
```

How search from the cache using

```
findAllByLocationEqualsAndNameEquals(String location, String name)
```

without making a DB call?Please suggest.